# Does it matter where I reduce a drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent

Central Valley, Hanford, California

I want to reduce a 4" line to 3" .. Is it best to reduce it horizontally or vertically, does it matter where I reduce?

I was thinking of reducing right before breaching the bottom-plate vertically (A) or reducing it on the horizontal run (B), is there a correct way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really three factors to consider:

- Access: How will it affect maintenance or future work?
- Function: Is there any concern about flow?
- Cost: What parts are least expensive?

Consider which are most important and go with it. As long as your initial pipe is large enough for its function it doesn't really matter. You may find that a reducing elbow, for example, saves cost and effort.